# Angular Router stopping data from being passed?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service trying to pass emit data which would be received by another component on init. When adding a route navigation, it stops the data from being received on init by the other component and I'm not sure why.

```
export class ListService {

    showLists = new Subject<List[]>();
    private createdLists: List[] = [];

    showCurrentList = new Subject<List>();
    private currentList: List;

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    createNewList(name: string) {
        const newList = this.createdLists.push({
            title: name
        });
        this.currentList = this.createdLists[newList - 1];
        
        this.showCurrentList.next({ ...this.currentList }); // this isn't being received when emitted****
        this.showLists.next(this.createdLists.slice());

        // before adding this line, the above emit worked******
        this.router.navigate(['/list', this.currentList]);
    }
```

Receiving component...

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  listSubscription: Subscription;
  currentList: List = { title: '', list: [{ task: '', completed: false }] };

  constructor(private listService: ListService, 
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listSubscription = this.listService.showCurrentList.subscribe(
      (list: List) => {
        console.log(list); //console.log reveals that nothing is being passed****
        this.currentList = list;
      }
    );    
  }
```

Comment: try enclosed the navigate in a setTimeout:`setTimeout(()=>{this.router.navigate(...)});`

Comment: That, unfortunately, didn't work. I wonder if it has something to do with my routing module, but I'm not sure. 
```{ path: 'list', component: ListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }, { path: 'list/:title', component: ListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }```
The submit button to create the list should redirect it to the List Component, but on init, it should add the route parameter based on the title of each list.

Comment: At last recurse, use navigateByUrl passing a variable to state, and in the component emit the value if state has the variable, https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb